# Create a dictionary using key sets

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 dictionary:

```
a = {'a':5, 'b':3, 'c':1}
b = {"ca":10, "sd":4, "aa":2}
```

What I want to obtain is:

```
z = {'a':"ca", 'b':"sd", 'c':"aa"}
```

How can I do this?

Edit:

I want to match the 1st key of a with the 1st key of b, the 2nd of a with the 2nd of b and so on.

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: @martineau  z[a.keys()[i]] = b.keys()[i]

Comment: Your question doesn't make it clear how to get to z from a and b.  You could be confused and think dicts preserve order; you could want to order the keys by decreasing values; or maybe something else entirely.  But one example doesn't suffice.

Comment: @DSM you are right my problem is that the order is not preserved. I want to match the 1st element of a with the 1st of b and so on

Comment: mata: Please put your attempt in your question. Not sure why you removed it,,, Regardless, in general you don't know what order the keys in a dictionary are in, so saying to match the 1st key of one with 1st key of another is almost meaningless (unless you don't care about which keys get paired).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a (now edited into ambiguity) comment you suggested that the ordering you had in mind was by "frequency".  Interpreting that as meaning ordering by dictionary value, you could make a new dict from zipping the keys sorted by the corresponding value:

```
In [14]: dict(zip(sorted(a, key=a.get), sorted(b, key=b.get)))
Out[14]: {'a': 'ca', 'b': 'sd', 'c': 'aa'}
```

This works because `a.get` is a method which gives us the values, so when we sort `a` (iteration of which is over the keys), we get them ordered by increasing value.

```
In [15]: sorted(a, key=a.get)
Out[15]: ['c', 'b', 'a']
```

This doesn't specify what to do in case of ties, though.  To handle that you could sort the argument to `sorted` (e.g. `sorted(sorted(a),key=a.get))`) or use a key function (e.g. `sorted(a, key=lambda x: (a[x], x))`) so that at least the output is deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = {'a':5, 'b':3, 'c':1}
b = {"ca":10, "sd":4, "aa":2}

print {a.keys()[i]:b.keys()[i] for i in range(len(a.keys()))}
```

Comment: There is no guarantee what order the keys in the two dictionary will be in.

Comment: I already tried this but the order is not preserved. See my edited message

Answer (score 0):

In that case you need to use `OrderedDict` to preserve the order. Here is an example:

```
import collections
import itertools

a = collections.OrderedDict()
b = collections.OrderedDict()

# add the data based on the order that you need
a['a'] = 5
a['b'] = 3
a['c'] = 1

b["ca"] = 10
b["sd"] = 4
b["aa"] = 2

# put them together. I user izip and iterkeys assuming you have a large data set
# also assuming the order in the new dictionary doesn't matter otherwise you have to use OrderedDict again.
z = {i: j for i, j in itertools.izip(a.iterkeys(), b.iterkeys())}

print z
>> {'a': 'ca', 'c': 'aa', 'b': 'sd'}
```